# Flattening a nested map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> nestedMap = [
  "x": [
    "a": 2,
    "b": 3,
    "c": 4
  ],
  "y": [
    "a": 20,
    "b": 30,
    "c": 40
  ],
  "z": [
    "a": 200,
    "b": 300,
    "c": 400
  ]
]
```

I want to flatten this structure and get:

```
[
  "x-a" : 2, 
  "x-b" : 3, 
  "x-c" : 4,
  "y-a" : 20, 
  "y-b" : 30, 
  "y-c" : 40,
  "z-a" : 200, 
  "z-b" : 300, 
  "z-c" : 400
]
```

How can I do this with `collect`/`collectEnteries` etc?

**Alternatively**, as you can see the values are quite similar. so the way I have constructed this nested map structure, was by running a for loop iterating through `[x,y,z]` and setting the entries of my map to be equal to a function that iterates through `[a,b,c]` and returns a map. Is there a way of skipping this nested structure and functionally append the elements in a big map?

Comment: Seems like a simple nested iteration over the original map keys and their values; what's the specific issue?

Comment: Instead of looping through [x, y, z], create a composite using both `[x,y,z]` and `[a,b,c]` and then call the function.

Comment: Something like `[['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c']].combinations().collect { "${it[0]}-${it[1]}" }` and then call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the alternate question (and echoing a comment by @damahapatro), consider the following.

Given two lists:

```
def list1 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
def list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

and a function `f` that gives the appropriate values, then we can use `inject` (which will accumulate a map while iterating over the combos (e.g. `[x,a]`):

```
def m = [list1, list2].combinations().inject([:]) { map, combo ->
    assert combo.size() == 2
    def a = combo[0]
    def b = combo[1]
    map["${a}-${b}" as String] = f(a,b)
    map
}

assert m == [
"x-a" : 2, "x-b" : 3, "x-c" : 4,
"y-a" : 20, "y-b" : 30, "y-c" : 40,
"z-a" : 200, "z-b" : 300, "z-c" : 400
]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a recursive function that will loop over the map and flatten it.

```
Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> nestedMap = [
"x": ["a": 2, "b": 3, "z": 4],
"y": ["a": 20, "b": 30, "c": 40],
"z": ["a": 200, "b": 300, "c": 400]
]

String concatenate(String k, String v) {
"${k}-${v}"
}

def flattenMap(Map map) {    
    map.collectEntries { k, v -> 
       v instanceof Map ? 
          flattenMap(v).collectEntries {  k1, v1 -> 
             key = concatenate(k,k1)
            [ (key): v1 ]  
         } :
            [ (k): v ]  
     } 
}


print flattenMap(nestedMap)​
```

Comment: be careful with `gstrings`. change "${k}-${k1}" to a function call to `
String concatenate(String k, String v) {
    "${k}-${v}"
}
`

Comment: `key` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of building the map from scratch would be:

```
def result = ['a'..'c', 'x'..'z']
    .combinations()
    .collect { a, b -> b + '-' + a }
    .indexed()
    .collectEntries { idx, name ->
        [name, ((idx % 3) + 2) * (int)Math.pow(10, idx.intdiv(3))]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified the define syntax of @Paul Walkington and tested it:

```
String concatenate(String k, String v) {
    "${k}-${v}"
}

def flattenMap(Map map) {
    map.collectEntries { k, v ->
        v instanceof Map ?
                flattenMap(v).collectEntries {  k1, v1 ->
                    def key = concatenate(k,k1)
                    [ (key): v1 ]
                } :
                [ (k): v ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do your task with a **single** istruction:

```
Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> nestedMap = [
  "x": ["a": 2, "b": 3, "c": 4],
  "y": ["a": 20, "b": 30, "c": 40],
  "z": ["a": 200, "b": 300, "c": 400] ]
result = nestedMap.inject([:]){ a, k, v ->
  a << v.collectEntries{ [k + '-' + it.key, it.value] }; a }
println result
```

(plus setting the source data, plus print the result).